# Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Inventario\controllers\Entrada\insertar.php on line 46

Tags: php, arrays

> Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Inventario\controllers\Entrada\insertar.php on line 46

My code:

```
$ref=$_POST['ref'];
$num=$_POST['num'];

$num=COUNT($num);   

for ($i=0; $i<$num; $i++){

    for ($j=2; $j < 12; $j++) { 
        # code...
        echo "<br>";
//ERROR AQUI
        echo $sqld="INSERT INTO detalle_orden (ord_cort_id, ref,color_id, talla,subtotal) 
                    VALUES ($ord_cort_id,". $ref[$i][0].",
                            ". $ref[$i][1].",". $ref[$i][$j].",".$ref[$i][12].")";
```

Comment: You should post the HTML form for this.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think that means "ERROR IS HERE"

Comment: @RiggsFolly I noticed the edit and edited my comment respectively ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- You are suppposed to be the cunning linguist, me I am just uni-linguist

Comment: @RiggsFolly You mean [like these guys?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CrOdBxXOQi4) - Just more "common" though.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oo nice bit of Purple never goes amiss

Comment: Are they going to help me or are they going to talk to each other? lol